# why My ios app is Background App refresh

Tags: ios, background, cllocationmanager

I am new to iOS development. I am using location services to get the user location in my app. 
When I stop updating the location, my app still appaears in in that Background App refresh list. How can i disable it programatically?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You do not want background App Refresh on your app?

Open your XCode Project -> Select your project -> Select Your App Target -> Under Capabilities -> Untick **Background Fetch** for **Background Modes**.

[image]

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but for my project background modes is in off state

Comment: @xarly yes, even though i am not using geofencing i have written the following line [self.locationManagerstartMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges], removing this line will remove the arrow frm my apprefresh